# Profile view count does not work on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, profile-page

I was looking at some profile pages on Area 51 and realized that the view counts are 0 for everyone. Is this a bug?

**EDIT:** [My profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/486/mehper-c-palavuzlar) shows **0 views**. There are too many users with 0 views. The problem seems to be present.

Comment: No, it is cache.

Comment: Why isn't it displayed then?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's broken. [Ivo's profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/16/ivo-flipse) has 0 views.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be broken. For my profile it has been stuck at 7 views since the early hours of 2010-07-01 (more than 7 months). (6 views on 2010-07-01T00:55:03 [UTC+1] and 7 views at 2010-07-01T08:16:05 [UTC+1]. It has been sampled 1273 times at 7 views since then...)

Answer (score 2):

Same problem for [my profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/4713/stefano-borini) as well. I think this should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

looks completed to me, as Ivo's profile now has 6 views.

Comment: My profile on Area 51 has been stuck at 1 for a while now. I am sure there is something wrong. Would you be able to check it out for me or do I have to post a question for this? Profile link: http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/6617/vivi

Comment: same problem with [my profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/4713/stefano-borini) stuck at zero.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have been fixed (likely between 2011-03-09T22:09:58Z and 2011-03-10T22:42:28Z). [My profile](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/84) have got about 2 views per day on average since then, compared to none in the 7 months before.

Comment: Mine still has 0 views.

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar: Yes, you are right. I just opened [your profile](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/users/486), and it is still at 0 views.

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar: You have 3 views now :-)

Comment: Let's hope it's really status-completed this time :)

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar: maybe. You have 8 views now, and I have 185 (the last one between 2011-05-14T15:36:10Z and 2011-05-14T22:03:25Z)